# Help-A-Noob-With-Ethereum-Wallet-Blockchain-Download

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, poloniex

I'm on a 2013 Macbook Pro / 16 GB ram / 512 SSD / 2.3 GHz

I just transferred 3 ETH from my poloniex account to the Ethereum Wallet on my local machine. The thing is, the entire blockchain hasn't finished downloading (stuck at 50% since 1.5 hours) and the balance ether is not reflecting in my local wallet. The exchange confirms that the transfer is accepted and confirmed.

I have quit the entire blockchain download and resorted to a --fast and --cache=2048 but even that is going very slowly. Sync first failed with and then imported new chain segment and started downloading slowly again.

At the time of posting, the last log reads:

> WARN [06-20|11:15:53] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="block body download canceled (requested)"

I'm a complete newb to crypto and this is my first attempt at transferring funds from an exchange to my personal wallet. What can I do to expedite this process / am I doing something wrong? I'm a little worried.

**ETA**

This is what the task log is reflecting now:

> WARN [06-20|11:20:09] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="block header download canceled (requested)"
>   WARN [06-20|11:23:41] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="receipt download canceled (requested)"

Comment: I'd suggest to try Parity https://parity.io/parity.html, it is more user friendly than geth, and totally compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry your funds are safe. Your balance wont display till your Ethereum wallet is fully synced up. You can confirm that your funds are in your account on etherscan.io

Answer (score 0):

is your hard drive full?
the blockchain will take a huge amount of space
i would check it before doing anything else
my advice is to get a cold storage unit (ledger) and send any currency to the address on the cold storage ledger.
they don't come cheap but will be safer and less time consuming